# Python Selecting menu choice

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming and I'm having trouble selecting an option. I have created a menu for example I have : 
Instructions 
Catering 
Packages
add 
When the user selects i, c, a or p each menu will come up. However, if the user selects 'p' before 'a' then I need to set a prompt to select a first..

```
INSTRUCTIONS = "I"
CATERING = "C"
PACKAGES = "P" 


    def menu():
        userInput = True 
        while userInput != False:
            print("Instructions
                   Catering
                    Packages")
            userInput = input(">>>")

        if userInput == INSTRUCTIONS:
            instructions()
        elif userInput == CATERING:
            Catering()
        elif userInput == PACKAGES:
            Packages()
        else:
             print("Error")
```

Thank you

Comment: Indeed, please show us your code and what you've tried already

Comment: This question contains almost no information. Post the code causing the problem, and post the specific problem.

Comment: Sorry, here is some of my code. I'm unsure about how I would go about writing code to prompt the user to choose packages before catering.

Comment: You might want to look at the [cmd](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule) package.

Comment: But, on the whole, why are you offering the user the option to select packages before they have selected catering if they can't do that?

Comment: *"if the user selects 'p' before 'a'..."* what input format do you expect? A single letter? A comma/whitespace-separated list of letters? And how do these options interact? If Catering/Packages need to store information and pass them between each other, you'll want to create a class with some data members. Or at least return some data structures from *Catering()* and pass into *Packages()*.

Comment: I'm working on an assignment and the this is one of the requirements-  to offer the option. I am still learning new things for this assignment.

Comment: If the user selects p before a I want it to print a prompt message like "load the package first" then the main menu will display again.Sorry.. I started learning python about 6 weeks ago.. It's a difficult process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Code in a Loop::

```
def menu():


 while True:
            u_in=raw_input("Input Here:: ")
            u=u_in.lower()
            if u_in=="":
                    continue

            elif u=="i":
                     Instructions()
            elif u=="c":
                    Catering()
            elif u=="p":
                    Packages()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python2.x, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

```
def menu():
    mybool == True

    userInput = input("Instructions\nCatering\nPackages\n>>> ")
    b = userInput.lower()[0]
    if b == 'a':
        mybool = True
    elif b == 'i':
        Instructions()
    elif b == 'c':
        Catering()
    elif b == 'p':
        if mybool == True:
            Packages()
        else:
            input('Here is where we display a prompt! ')
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Basically, this sets a variable to be `False`, and then gets input. If the input is `a`, then we set `myBool` to be `True`. If the user selects `p` and `myBool` is `True` (`a` has already been selected), it carries on. Otherwise, it displays a prompt.